# NextJs 14 API to Return PDF

Tags: reactjs, node.js, pdf, next.js

I am trying to write a Nextjs 14 API to return a PDF document for display in the page.

Tee pdf is located in the public/reports directory.  The API needs to read the file and return it in the response.

I am not sure of the approach to read the file and pass it back in the response.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code i have so far.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse} from "next/server";
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path'

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse,  context:any) {

    const filePath = path.resolve('.', 'public/reports/sample.pdf')
    const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath)
    res.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')

    return res.blob
    
};
```